# using backup sets when performing transaction log backups

Tags: sql-server, backup

we have an install of sharepoint so we have many databases that we are currently backing up. Currently we are running full, diff and transaction log backups.  Consequently we end up with a fair few transaction log backups per day.  Currently a file is created for every log backup which equals alot of files.  This is going to be a nightmare in a restore situation.

Im wondering whether i should use a backup set for the transaction logs but have never used this option before.  Ive tested one and the log backups get dumped into one bak file which i think would help the restore process, but im a bit confused about the expires option.  What does this actually do?  Are the log backups removed after the duration.  Are the still available for restore?  IS using a backup set for just the transaction logs a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

You say "backup set" in your question, but you probably mean a "media set". One Backup operation creates one backup set. One media set can contain multiple backup sets. Expiry options are set per backup set.

So, putting backups that will be used together in a restore in a common media set is a good idea IMO, because it indeed helps to have fewer files to manage in a restore situation.

Now to the options. Backup sets in a media set (disk file or tape) can have individual expiry dates, but if you use append mode (NOINIT), new backup sets will just be appended. You can reuse a media set when all backup sets on it are expired **and** you specify INIT **and** you specify NOSKIP.

The most common way to handle this situation with file based backups is to avoid the whole SKIP/NOKSIP/INIT/EXPIRY mess altogether and use one media set per day per database with a date in the file name. Then you use a maintenance cleanup task or a scheduled task from the OS to remove files you no longer need in regular intervals.

A more elaborate alternative would be to use for example one file (or tape) for each week day, with all backup sets to expire within less than a week. On the first backup of the day you use INIT,NOSKIP to clean up the media set and NOINIT for further backups on that day. This spares you from deleteing old files, but creates handling problems if your first backup of the day fails for some reason. You can script around that by testing before each backup if all backup sets on the media are expired and use INIT only in this case, but still its not as robust as the first approach.

Comment: will it overwrite expired backups even if it is set as append.

Comment: Oops, I confused backup sets and media sets. I'll rewrite my answer shortly.

Comment: ok that makes sense.  Currently we run 1 full backup a week, daily diffs and hourly trans backups so i would only really need to do this for the trans backups as the others are infrequent enough not to be a pain when restoring.  Can you point me in the direction of how to create the backup filename with a date in it for each database.

Comment: Here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410674/add-date-to-sql-database-backup-filename